# chart.js react-chartjs-2 and chartjs-plugin-streaming dependency error

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to replicate [this example](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/latest/tutorials/react/stream.html) to draw a Line chart that can handle stream data. It requires chart.js, react-chartjs-2, and chartjs-plugin-streaming.

I tried to install these packages in the order mentioned. However, I ran into this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt2xA.png

Any suggestions on how to overcome this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chartjs-plugin-streaming` requires chart.js version 3, see the "COMPATIBILITY NOTE" in the [introduction section of its docs](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/latest/guide/#table-of-contents).

So, one solution is to downgrade your chart.js version from 4.2.1 (latest) to one of the 3 versions. The documentation of the site `chartjs.org` is still alive for a lot of old versions, just select the version from the dropdown on the top of the page.

`react-charts-2` also supports both versions 3 and versions 4 of `chart.js`. Here's the [guide](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/docs/chartjs-v3) on how to use `react-chart-2` with `chart.js` v3

Alternatively, you may consider if you really need the plugin. It does offer some convenience and some advanced features. However, the current options for updating the charts [see the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) are quite strong, and in combination with current tools for getting the data over the net like `fetch` or `axios` you'll be able to do the same things, and enjoy the use of the updated versions of all tools.

As an example, here's a very basic update sequence based only
on `chart.js` v4 `update` functionality:

```js
const NData = 200,
    nUpdate = 3, dt = 100,
    dataGenerator = (from, to) => Array.from({length: to-from+1}, (_, i)=>Math.sin((i+from)*2*Math.PI/NData*4)*(1+Math.random()));

const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: Array.from({length: NData+1}, (_,i)=>'@'+(i/NData*100).toFixed(0)+'%'),
        datasets: [{
            label:'sin*(1+noise)',
            pointStyle: 'circle',
            lineTension: 0.2,
            borderColor: '#479',
            pointRadius: 0,
            data: dataGenerator(0, NData-1)
        }]
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales:{
            x:{
                ticks: {
                    maxTicksLimit: 10.1
                }
            },
            y:{
                min: -2,
                max: 2
            }
        },
        //animation:{duration:0},
    }
});

let current = NData-1;

let ih = setInterval(updateChart, dt);
const button = document.querySelector('#pause');
button.onclick = function(){
    if(ih){
        clearInterval(ih);
        ih = 0;
        button.innerText = 'Continue';
    }
    else{
        ih = setInterval(updateChart, 100);
        button.innerText = 'Pause';
    }
}

function updateChart() {
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data.splice(0, nUpdate);
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(...dataGenerator(current+1, current+nUpdate));
    current+=nUpdate;
    myChart.update('none');
}
```

```html
<div style="height:300px; width:95vw; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid gray">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-vCUbejtS+HcWYtDHRF2T5B0BKwVG/CLeuew5uT2AiX4SJ2Wff52+kfgONvtdATqkqQMC9Ye5K+Td0OTaz+P7cw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script></body>
```

Comment: I tried downgrading my chart.js but it seems the conflict is between react-chartjs-2 and chartjs-plugin-streaming. I will probably just skip using the plugin as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: I added [this link](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/docs/chartjs-v3) to the solution they propose for using `react-chartjs-2` with `chart.js` v3.